# How to install one site inside another with Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a wordpress multisite on centos 6.5 at /var/www/html/site1
accessible at site1.com and everything there is fine.

I would like to install a single site called site2 at
/var/www/html/site2 but
accessible at site1.com/site2

The .conf for site1 has a server block like this:

```
            location / {
                         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                       }

            #editing here to...
            location /site2 {
                root /var/www/html/site2/;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files /index.html /index.php $uri $uri/;
             }

             location ~ /site2/(.*\.php)$ {
                root /var/www/html/site2/;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$1;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                     fastcgi_index  index.php;
                     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                     include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                 }

            }

          #end editing.
```

When I use try files try_files /index.html /index.php $uri $uri/; it works.
When I use try_files try_files /index.php $uri $uri/; the browser downloads the file instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

The location block should do the trick as long as you define a new root for the location:

```
location /site2
{
  root /var/www/html/site2;

  #put your rewrite rules here
}
```

You have to make sure that your fastcgi (I assume you'r using php-fpm) configuration uses the new docroot as well.
I don't know wordpress very well, but I reckon you also have to configure the second site to be in a subdirectory called `/site2`, otherwise links might not work properly.

Comment: Will play with this soon. Thx for the response.

Comment: I got close but no cigar. Even with a blank index.php in site2 I get a site1 404. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please update your question and post the entire configuration file? Also, please check whether the 404 is generated by wordpress or nginx. Nginx incercepts fastcgi errors and displays it's own 404 page per default:

Comment: Can you please update the question and post your entire nginx configuration? Also, please check whether the 404 is generated by WordPress or Nginx. Nginx intercepts all error response codes and displays its own error page per default. You have to set `fastcgi_intercept_errors off;` in your fastcgi block. Then your will either see a 404 by wordpress, meaning wordpress can't parse the url, or a 404 by Nginx, meaning your path configuration is wrong

Comment: I updated the question with most of my config. As I've been trouble shooting my issue has changed. Now my index.html page serves but index.php gets downloaded.